# unmet dependencies for php5-mysql

Tags: packages, mysql, owncloud, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to get owncloud running on a Raspberry Pi 3 to run as a local file server. I'm following some tutorials that are running me through setting up mysql for owncloud, and MySQL installed fine for the most part. I run into an error when trying to install the package `php5-mysql`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

This piece is crucial to link MySQL to owncloud, so I can't go farther without this. Raspbian Stretch is installed. I don't know how to proceed and have very little database/MySQL/Apache experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71473/unable-to-install-mysql

Comment: checked, and none of solutions from attached question work. Should this get marked as duplicate? I don't know how I can help on other question since I can't comment. thoughts?

Comment: If there is no answer that solves your problem, then it should not be marked as duplicate, but you might want to watch the other question as well, in case a helpful answer appears.

Comment: I found an answer here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71473/unable-to-install-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1 "I managed to install with: sudo apt-get install php-mysql It appears that PHP 7 packages are then installed instead of the 5 version.
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php5-mysql is available in the previous version Jessie and NOT in Stretch.

But Owncloud should be able to use php7 (php-mysql)!

Ref.: https://owncloud.org/blog/php-7-is-here-and-owncloud-is-ready/